# How to solve $x^TAy = d$, where $A$ and $d$ are known, x and y remain unknown.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

How to solve $x^TAy = d$, where $A$ and $d$ are known, $x$ and $y$ remain unknown.
$x$ and $y$ are vectors; $A$ is a matrix; $d$ is a scalar.

There are constraints for $x$ and $y$, requiring $x$ and $y$ sums up to 1, and all elements greater equal than zero, i.e., $x^T \mathbf{1} = 1, x \geq \mathbf{0}$ and $y^T \mathbf{1} = 1, y \geq \mathbf{0}$

There may be infinite solutions, but I just need one.

Comment: Just write $x^T=(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ and $y^T=(y_1,\ldots y_m)$ and compute the equations. Then it is easy to solve it.

Comment: You just pick a solution for the resulting quadratic.

Comment: If $d$ is nonzero you can arrange this by finding any pair of vectors for which $x^T A y$ is nonzero (if they exist; this assumes nonzeroness of $A$) and then just scaling one of them so you get $d$ instead of what it might have been.   If $d$ is zero there are obvious solutions.

Comment: The resulting quadratic will look like $a_{11}*x_1y_1 + \dots+a_{nn}*x_ny_n=d$, but how to pick one solution, just one.

Comment: $x^T=(d/a_{11},0,0,....)$ and $y^T=(1,0,0,....)$